# Why onNext() be called two times when I use doOnSubscribe()

Tags: android, rx-java

just like this sample

```
  Observable.fromCallable(() -> okHttp.getDataFromNet(page))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(()->{adapter.loadmore})
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    adapter.stopLoad();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                  Log.e("fail","fail");
                  adapter.add();
                }
            });
```

I find `onNext`will be called two times in this case.If i add `Log.e()` in
`onCompleted()`,it also will called two times.What is wrong about my code.What is the reason that if a method will be called in Subscriber ,then I add `doOnSubscribe()` it will be called two times。

```
//progressbarAdapter extends Recyclerview.Adapter
static final int LOADING_TYPE = -1;
private boolean isLoading = false;
 public void loadingMore(){
    isLoading = true;
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
    // size = index +1
}
public void loadingEnd(){
    notifyItemRemoved(getItemCount());
    isLoading = false;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getDataCount() + (isLoading ? 1: 0);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == getDataCount() && !isError){
        return LOADING_TYPE;
    }else {
        return getExtItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

### the real reason

**when adapter.notify it will trigger scroll methods,so it will be called two times. I am sorry for that I asked a bad question.**

Comment: Try to romve .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

Comment: I need view on main thread

Comment: Where is this observable declared? When is that code called?

Comment: `Recyclerview.addOnScrollListener()`When scroll to bottom,it will be called.

Comment: Obviously `RecyclerView` fires the callback two times.

Comment: @azizbekian can you tell me the reason

Comment: You should not make assumptions how many times this callback is fired, because as user performs scroll plenty of touch events are happening and you may receive multiple callbacks for the same state. Let's assume, that scroll position of Y=300 would mean that the end has reached. As soon as user scrolls, Y reaches 299 then 300, and then may become again 299 (because user is still playing around) and then again 300. I am not sure how the overscrolling will affect it, e.g. how fling would affect that callback.

Answer (score 1):

please have a look how to use observeOn and subscribeOn. There can only be one subscribeOn for an observable. If you use multiple, the last one wins. Use observeOn to switch threads between pipelines and subscribeOn to specify the thread which will create the observable.

I transformed your given code in order to use it in a test. I only get one onNext-call.

Problem: getting called two times.
This may be because of wrong usage of the observable somewhere else in the code by flatMap or multiple subscriptions to observable. Please provide more context.

Testenvironment: IntelliJ Idea 2017 EAP, io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Observable<String> doOnSub = Observable.just("1")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
                System.out.println("doOnSub");
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation());

    TestSubscriber<String> objectTestSubscriber = TestSubscriber.create();

    doOnSub.subscribe(objectTestSubscriber);


    objectTestSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
    objectTestSubscriber.assertValues("1");
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for my code，I need a RecyclerView Adapter with progressbar。`doOnSubscribe(() - >{adapter.loadMore})` and `onNext((x) - >adapter.add(x))` ,`onCompleted(() ->adapter.stopLoadMore)`.They need work in main thread. I think I can not block thread in`doOnSubscribe()`.

Comment: What does loadMore, stopLoadMore do? You need to provide more context what you are trying to achieve. Maybe we will finde another solutions.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I am update the more context.I try to find other ways to show this problem but fail. I can not find the real reason about this.